# Rails4 ログイン認証 Devise omniauth-facebook　<% if f.object.password_required? %>が効いていない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ログイン認証で下記のgemを使用しています。
・Devise
・omniauth-facebook

omniauth-facebook認証時にuser_nameを追加で入力させたいです。
user_nameカラムを追加し、viewに

```
 <%= f.text_field :user_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "ユーザネーム",id: "login-name" %>
      </div>
```

を追加すると、user_name以外に、パスワードの入力を求められるようになりました。
パスワードを入力すると通常の登録はできますがfacebook認証となりません（uid,nameなどが取れていない状態）

facebook認証時にはpassword入力を求めないようにpassword_required?メソッドcontrollerに追加し、viewには<% if f.object.password_required? %>を追加しましたが
動作しませんでした。

facebook認証時user_nameのみを入力項目とし、パスワードの入力を求めないように
実装するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか

因みにuser_nameカラムと

```
<%= f.text_field :user_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "ユーザネーム",id: "login-name" %>
      </div>
```

を追加する前はワンクリックでfacebook認証可能でした。

**#user.rb**

```
 validates :user_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true


 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
     user.provider = auth.provider
     user.uid      = auth.uid
     user.name     = auth.info.name
     user.email    = auth.info.email
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
 end

 def self.new_with_session(params, session)
   super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
      user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
     end
   end
 end

 def self.current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user]
 end

 def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
 end
```

**#omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

**#registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="login-form">
      <p>新規登録</p>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do%>
            <div class="btn-sm btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebookで登録
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="login-field-icon fui-mail" for="user_name"></label>
        <%= f.text_field :user_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "ユーザネーム",id: "login-name" %>
      </div>

      <% if f.object.password_required? %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-mail" for="email"></label>
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "Email",id: "login-name" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "Password",id: "login-pass" %>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control login-field",placeholder: "Password確認用",id: "login-pass" %>

          </div>
          <p class="palette-paragraph">半角英数字8文字以上</p>
      <% end %>
      <br>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <%= f.submit "登録する", class: 'btn btn-embossed btn-sm btn-block  btn-warning ' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**サーバログ**

> Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCb50YD18DG8vYG0h6gBQl-tjdoi2bupij4e138eFhfrwSXS_lIShlaJ27AM3TRQQHozaE7yI4zYgjI5Pv11Ojv8HvamGEn5pTvo4obImWbmq41QBbERe-8LUBWZuwdFCa2iwj8MmV4V4eAD678L_YfaUiYZUOII6CJOcrOcjs-rVFXOMK5Ssi8SvZtEDyqRg535Zz5aVg8DdErest8tl1nCTQETxX526LhwXoFYvb7sWlpAgb3m1nlCz7nCAbTdpAqe8uHk9-p02IfUBFvFDv4x1qb2x_DT7D64eouxae3KgonR4z7sssmfKie-BKs43c&state=2e2edfb450620fdb442d92acad47e24723fc04582d073264" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-30 01:43:29 +0900
>   Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
>     Parameters: {"code"=>"AQCb50YD18DG8vYG0h6gBQl-tjdoi2bupij4e138eFhfrwSXS_lIShlaJ27AM3TRQQHozaE7yI4zYgjI5Pv11Ojv8HvamGEn5pTvo4obImWbmq41QBbERe-8LUBWZuwdFCa2iwj8MmV4V4eAD678L_YfaUiYZUOII6CJOcrOcjs-rVFXOMK5Ssi8SvZtEDyqRg535Zz5aVg8DdErest8tl1nCTQETxX526LhwXoFYvb7sWlpAgb3m1nlCz7nCAbTdpAqe8uHk9-p02IfUBFvFDv4x1qb2x_DT7D64eouxae3KgonR4z7sssmfKie-BKs43c", "state"=>"2e2edfb450620fdb442d92acad47e24723fc04582d073264"}
>     User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = '10204167973454999'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'xxxxxxxxx@yahoo.co.jp' LIMIT 1
>     User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."user_name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>      (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
>   Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_up
>   Completed 302 Found in 122ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
>   Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-30 01:43:30 +0900
>   Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
>     Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: 「今何ができていて何ができていないのか」「どういうことがしたくて、今何に困っているのか」をもう一度整理して書き直してほしいです。質問文を読んでもそのあたりが理解できませんでした。

Comment: 失礼しました。追加と修正を行いました。

Answer (score 2):

Userモデルには`name`と`user_name`が別々に存在しているのでしょうか？（コードを見る限りそのように見えます）

やりたいことは「Facebook経由でアカウント登録する場合も、名前だけは画面で入力した名前（user_name）を使いたい」ということだと理解しましたが、おそらくそれは無理、もしくは非常に面倒くさいと思います。

Facebook認証を使ったときはあくまでFacebookから返ってきた情報しかアカウント登録に使えないので、画面で入力したuser_nameは無視されます。（仕組み的にはFacebookのサイトへ移動して戻ってくるだけなので、画面の入力値はRails側に送信されない）

というわけで、そもそも「それは無理」という話になるのですが、それとは別に「パスワードの入力を求められる」という問題についても回答しておきます。
こちらはコードを見ていると user_name の必須チェックに引っかかっているのが原因じゃないかと思います。

`validates :user_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true`をコメントアウトするか、`user.name = user.user_name = auth.info.name`と書くなどして、user_nameの必須チェックエラーを発生させないようにすればFacebook経由でのアカウント登録もうまくいくのではないでしょうか？（ただし前述の通り、画面で入力したuser_nameは使われません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。ほかのサイトではfacebook認証時でもユーザネームを入力させています。そしてユーザプロフィールを見るとhttp://0.0.0.0:3000/profiles/1ではなくhttp://0.0.0.0:3000/profiles/ユーザ名となっています。それと同じことをしたくて色々試しています。因みにuser modelとprofile modelはhas_oneです。